# calling CoCreateInstanceEx with ipv6

Tags: visual-c++, ipv6, dcom

I'm trying to call CoCreateInstanceEx by passing an ipv6 address, but it fails with access denied.  Is there a way around this, or is it not supported?  Here is a snipet:

```
       COSERVERINFO serverinfo;
        ZeroMemory( &serverinfo, sizeof serverinfo);
        serverinfo.pwszName = (OLECHAR *)sAddress.c_str();
        MULTI_QI qi[2];
        qi[0].pIID = &IID_IUnknown;
        qi[0].pItf = NULL;
        qi[0].hr = S_OK;
        qi[1].pIID = &IID_IXSMyIniitialize;
        qi[1].pItf = NULL;
        qi[1].hr = S_OK;
        HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstanceEx( 
            CLSID_CoSMyCOM, 
            0, 
            CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER | CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER,
            &serverinfo,
            2,
            qi);
```

If sAddress is something like 10.7.10.10, it works.  But, if it is something like fe90::a877:d1aa:43f7:5922 I get access denied.  Both addresses point to the same server.  Thanks.

Comment: Is the server to which it points on your same layer-2 LAN?

Comment: Yes, I'm actually calling it from the same machine where the COM server is.

Comment: OK. You are using an address in the `fe80::/10` link-local network, and every interface in a host uses the same `fe80::/10` link-local network, so you must include the scope in the link-local address to identify the particular interface you mean to use. If you use a port with an IPv6 address, you need to surround the address with `[` and `]` before appending the `:port`, and some applications require the brackets, anyway.

Comment: Thanks, it was the zone index what I was missing (i.e.%10).  I did have the brackets around the address, I just left them out of my post.  Incidentally, CoCreateInstanceEx works with, or without brackets.  I just have to have the zone index.

Comment: @user1375218 I think you meant to write `fe80::...`, not `fe90::...`. The latter is not a valid (i.e. currently defined) address prefix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see my comment above, it was the zone index that I was missing.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, an answer really needs to demonstrate the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: What I meant was the address, e.g. fe80::a877:d1aa:43f7:5922, must be followed by the zone id, e.g. fe80::a877:d1aa:43f7:5922%10.  There is no need to edit the code snippet since the address wasn't hard coded. Thanks.